# How to get Woocommerce order product info

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic

I am trying to get all woocommerce orders and find info about the products in each order. I have seen many examples on here and elsewhere on the web and they all seem to say to do the same thing but it isn't working. I am on Wordpress 4.1.1 and Woocommerce 2.3.3 here is my code:

```
$filters = array(
    'post_status' => 'any',
    'post_type' => 'shop_order',
    'posts_per_page' => 200,
    'paged' => 1,
    'orderby' =>'modified',
    'order' => 'ASC'
);

$loop = new WP_Query( $filters );

while ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
    $loop->the_post();
    $order = new WC_Order($loop->post->ID);

    foreach ($order->get_items() as $key => $lineItem) {
        print_r($lineItem);
    }
}
```

The problem is when I `print_r($lineItem)` there are only three properties only two of which are ever populated. A typical `print_r($lineItem)` looks like this:

```
Array ( 
    [name] => Fouta Towel – Pearl Grey & White Stripe 
    [type] => line_item 
    [item_meta] => 
)
```

How do I get the rest of the information about this order item, e.g the product id, whether it is a single / variable product etc

Answer (score 7):

Have tried your code and it works fine and infact it also gives out the details of each product in the orders. The code which i tried

```
$filters = array(
    'post_status' => 'any',
    'post_type' => 'shop_order',
    'posts_per_page' => 200,
    'paged' => 1,
    'orderby' => 'modified',
    'order' => 'ASC'
);

$loop = new WP_Query($filters);

while ($loop->have_posts()) {
    $loop->the_post();
    $order = new WC_Order($loop->post->ID);

    foreach ($order->get_items() as $key => $lineItem) {

        //uncomment the following to see the full data
        //        echo '<pre>';
        //        print_r($lineItem);
        //        echo '</pre>';
        echo '<br>' . 'Product Name : ' . $lineItem['name'] . '<br>';
        echo 'Product ID : ' . $lineItem['product_id'] . '<br>';
        if ($lineItem['variation_id']) {
            echo 'Product Type : Variable Product' . '<br>';
        } else {
            echo 'Product Type : Simple Product' . '<br>';
        }
    }
}
```

And the output i got from the same.

[image]

Try this and let me know how it works for you

Comment: it works but it creates problem when i try to use it inside the class ..and when i access it it throws me Uncaught Exception: Invalid order

Comment: also $loop->the_post(); is it required?